# Unable to set Text in Combox Box in DropDownList

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to set the text in a combo box. Below is the code-

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox selectModel;
this.selectModel = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
this.selectModel.Name = "selectModel";
this.selectModel.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.selectModel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 21);
this.selectModel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 76);
this.selectModel.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

The following line is not working-

```
selectModel.SelectedText = getModelNameFromConf();
```

The documentation says that *"it Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a ComboBox"*. I can't make it editable to user.

Any workaround please.

Comment: Is it a Windows Forms application? Why the ASP.NET tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you use `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`, the dropdown has no editable portion. To make it editable, use `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`.

Note too the [remarks on the SelectedText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx) relating to whether the control has focus. You may find the `Text` property more suitable for many purposes.

**EDIT** For example:

```
selectModel.Text = getModelNameFromConf();
```

Assuming the combo contains that value in its list, setting `Text` will also set the `SelectedIndex` property of the dropdown.

(I think some of the property names of this control are particularly confusing, including `DropDown` vs. `DropDownList`. Someone at MS had a bad day when this control was coded. Note also that the word *selection* is being used in two different ways: here, you want to set the selected item, whereas `SelectedText` means some text that is selected—which might not be the whole of the item text. This is the same as in a textbox where the user has dragged the mouse to highlight some of the text but not all of it.)

Comment: `Text` Property? Can you please write it completely? I observed that I can change the current item by using `selectModel.SelectedIndex`. I just wanted to display the item, which already exists in `selectModel`. Suppose, combo box contains d,b,c,a,e,k items. combo box is displaying d. Now I want to display c. One thing I can do is first find out the index then set, which is little overhead. Instead of it, I was thinking to set the text.

Comment: @RaviJoshi I've expanded my answer with info about those points.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your side note is very useful :)